# Facing npm error installing ng-connection-service in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, npm-install, nuget-package, package.json

I need to install ng-connection-service in angular but I get this error while trying to install Could not resolve dependency.I have to send this code to azure devops as well so pls let me know how to install this package correctly so that package installation will work fine when I send to azure too..

```
D:\Project\apps\ClientApp>npm i ng-connection-service@1.0.4
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: c360apps@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"8.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from ng-connection-service@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/ng-connection-service
npm ERR!   ng-connection-service@"1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular 8, but ng-connection-service says it only knows how to work with Angular 6 - most likely because they didn't update their library in a long time.

Some ideas to move forward on:

1. Have a look at https://github.com/ultrasonicsoft/ng-connection-service - it seems to be an Angular8-compatible replacement for the library you're trying to use.
2. Use "npm i --force" to install ng-connection-service@1.0.4 over Angular 8 and then test carefully
3. Downgrade to Angular 6 and try again
4. Ask ng-connection-service if they would update their library to make it compatible with Angular 7+, then install a newer version of ng-connection-service once it becomes available.

Comment: The docs at your link in (1) say it's for Angular 8 but the install for it is the package the original question is talking about (?). I have run into this issue using `ng-connection-service`. I think something is wonky with the dependencies connected with it. Somehow I got my project working with it and Angular 8 several months ago, but then a couple days ago it decided to start giving me the issue *only* during *publish* build from *my* machine (coworker can publish from his computer just fine). I can run from source from my computer, but not publish. Frustrating